# Translation animation

Tags: android, animation, translation

i have a page which includes translation animation. It works on a button click.This page also includes a list view. My problem is if there is no item in list view then translation animation doesn't works on button click. But if the list view has a single item the animation works fine. Is anyone know what the problem is? 
Below is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgnd_text_color">

//parent layout

<com.supportfiles.mypackage.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="@color/orange_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<include layout="@layout/my_sliding_layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The function for animation is below

```
 public void slidingAnimation(int animateFromX, int animateToX, final int marginX){
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(animateFromX, animateToX, 0, 0);
    slide.setDuration(300);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {       
            contentParams.setMargins(marginX, 0, 0, 0);         
            menu.setLayoutParams(contentParams);

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
    });
    menu.startAnimation(slide);     

}
```

menu is the parent relative layout in my_sliding_layout.xml

i am  calling slidingAnimation() function in button click but the sliding animation works only if the pull to refresh listview has items. If listview is empty then animation doesn,t works. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you are applying animation to list view or parent layout?

Comment: not for listview. its a relative layout inside the main layout

Comment: To solve the problem we need to see your code, that you've used for animation. We can't guess the reason.

Comment: i have posted the code

Comment: does anyone know about it

Comment: i have no experience in this issue, but it looks sense to me, as empty list has height=0 ,when height is wrap_content,,, maybe so the animation will not appear.... just curious what happens if you set listView height="80dp" ?